# Simple sidebar Jquery/Html/Css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a sidebar but I have a problem when using media queries. If the window is smaller than 991 i am not able to toggle the side menu again.

https://jsfiddle.net/k4wgnned/7/

So I will need something like this. **(this doesn't work because it will click the menu everytime i resize)**. How can I do this?

```
$(window).resize(function () {
   var width = $(window).width();

   if(width < 991) {
       //to hide
       $('#sidebar-btn').click();
   }
   else {
       //to show
       $('#sidebar-btn').click();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check below jsfiddle sample of custom responsive menu

```js
var _init = function(){
    var touchBtn = $('.responsiveButton'),
        body = $('body'),
        vsMenu = $('.vsMenu'),
        vsMenuPosition = parseInt(vsMenu.css('left')),
        vsMenuWidth = parseInt(vsMenu.width()),
        windowWidth = parseInt($(window).width());

    var _open = function(this_){
        this_.addClass('vsMenuOpen');
        vsMenu.scrollTop(0);
        vsMenu.animate({
            left: '0'
        });
        body.animate({
            left: vsMenuWidth
        });
        body.addClass('vsMenuBody');
        body.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            overflow: 'hidden',
            width: windowWidth
        });
        //$('.headerWrap').css({
            //width: windowWidth
        //});
    }

    var _close = function(this_){
        this_.removeClass('vsMenuOpen');
        vsMenu.animate({
            left: -vsMenuWidth
        }, function () {
            vsMenu.removeAttr('style');
        });
        body.stop().animate({
            left: '0'
        }, function () {
            body.removeClass('vsMenuBody');
            body.removeAttr('style');
            //$('.headerWrap').removeAttr('style');
        });

    } 

    touchBtn.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        vsMenuPosition = parseInt(vsMenu.css('left'));
        if (vsMenuPosition == -vsMenuWidth) {
            _open($(this));
        } else {
           _close($(this));
        }
    }); 

    $('body').click(function() {
        vsMenuPosition = parseInt(vsMenu.css('left'));        
        if (vsMenuPosition === 0) {
            _close(touchBtn);
        }
    });
    $('body').on("click", ".vsMenu", function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(window).resize(function() {
        windowWidth = parseInt($(window).width());
        vsMenuWidth = parseInt(vsMenu.width());
        touchBtn = $('.responsiveButton');
        if(windowWidth >767){
            if(touchBtn.hasClass('vsMenuOpen')) {
                touchBtn.trigger('click');
            }
        }
    });
};  

$(document).ready(function() {
   _init();
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin:0;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.source {
    position: static;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 50px;
    right: 50px;
}
pre code.python {
    display: block;
    padding: .2em;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.container {
    width: 640px;
    margin: auto;
}
/******************* Desktop Menu *******************/
 .vsMenu {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}
.vsMenu li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
.vsMenu li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.responsiveButton {
    display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .container {
        width: auto;
        padding: 50px
    }
    /******************* Responsive Menu *******************/
    .vsMenuBody {
        position: absolute
    }
    .responsiveButton {
        background: #0E0E0E;
        display: block;
        padding: 5px 15px;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1000;
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
    }
    .icon-bar {
        background-color: #F5F5F5;
        border-radius: 1px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        display: block;
        height: 2px;
        width: 18px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0);
        transform: rotate(0);
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 80ms ease-out;
        transition: transform 80ms ease-out;
        margin: 4px 0
    }
    .vsMenuOpen .icon-bar {
        background: #000;
    }
    .vsMenuOpen .icon-bar:first-child, 
    .vsMenuOpen .icon-bar:last-child {
        background: #fff;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .vsMenuOpen .icon-bar:first-child {
        top: 0.5em;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
    .vsMenuOpen .icon-bar:last-child {
        top: -0.5em;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    .vsMenu {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 999999;
        width: 260px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        background: #F2F2F2;
        color: #333;
        left: -260px;
        box-shadow: -12px 0 8px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset
    }
    .vsMenu li {
        float: none;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .vsMenu li a {
        display:block;
        padding: 10px;
        color: #be2025;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom:1px solid #58585a
    }
    .vsMenu li a:hover {
        background: #58585a;
        color: #ffffff
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"> <a class="responsiveButton" href="#">
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</a>

    <div class="vsMenu">
        <ul class="navig">
            <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 6</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont want any of this. I just want a solution to my problem.